# Return a value on the console when the application terminates

Tags: unity-game-engine, console, return-value, exit

I would like to know if it is possible to return a value or a string as desired when the application (the game itself) ends. A program launched by a terminal should return something. Here, I'm writing a game on Unity3D and I need to run it with the terminal and then read a value when the execution is finished (return value and process). How can I do?

Please note that I am referring to the console through which I launch the game (either Terminal.app on MacOS or CMD on Windows).

Comment: By "read a value" you mean like a high score or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that too, but not only. Since I'm working for a company that has to develop a videogame application for a particular therapy in hospitals, I can not decide how to return the values. They need the game to run from another program (launcher) that expects return values ​​when it ends.

Comment: I am not sure how to return a value directly to CMD from unity :/ Maybe try checking com ports if you did not before. You can write and read both from Unity

Comment: Do you need specific exit values or will a generic zero suffice?  It seems your best option is going to be creating a middle-man shell script as Unity flat out does not support exit codes.

Comment: Probably I will need the support of a script as you say, as the format should be (seems) a JSON string. The other, less preferred option is the use of a Web Service using an HTTP POST.

Comment: Crosspost at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159895/return-a-value-on-the-console-when-the-application-terminates

Comment: @kitsune I don't think you're asking for an exit code, then, if it needs to be anything other than an integer on application exit.  If that's the case, then you can script it in Unity.